# How can I repeat a custom function mapped using `vnoremap` using something similar to the dot (`.`) operator?

Tags: visual-mode, repeated-commands

I have this custom function in my `~/.vimrc` mapped to Visual mode using `vnoremap`.

After having executed the function using `<leader><space>`, how execute it again using something similar to the dot (`.`) operator, so that I don't have two press to keys?

```
function! Visual_indent_with_space() range abort
   '<,'>g/./exe "normal! " v:count1 . "I "
   :normal gv
endfunction

vnoremap <leader><space> :call Visual_indent_with_space()<cr>
```

Comment: It has to be explicitly supported by programming. See the _repeat_  plugin that emulates the feature.